# Use tracing when extending linestrings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, linestring, snapping, tracing

In QGIS 3 it is possible to extend an existing linestring by clicking on the 'virtual endpoint' cross marker as described in https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/de/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#digitizing-an-existing-layer

When extending a linestring along an existing feature, tracing seems not to work. Seems that I have to digitize along the feature by snapping to each of its vertices as shown here (the dotted line should trace along the thin black one, but doesn't):

[image: example]

This is a) time consuming and b) a source for errors.

I wonder if tracing does not work when extending a line string, is this not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the line extension feature, perhaps try the [Reshape Features tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#reshape-features)? This allows you to extend the line while also allowing tracing.

You may need to select the specific feature you want to extend before using Reshape Features if you have a lot of features in the same area.

[image]